# How does a sentry prioritize targets?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

```
             H
      {o}

      D      S
```

The S in this case is the sentry.
The D is a demoman, running towards sentry with Grenade Launcher.
The H is a heavy, firing at the sentry.
The o is a scout, and he is concurrently capping a point ({}signifies a cap point)

Will the sentry shoot the scout first?  Demoman first?   How does it pick its targets?  Is it random?

Comment: Whatever's closest to the sentry will draw fire - even if the target is invalid (ie, an ubercharged player or a Scout with Bonk!).  Typically if you're a medic ubering another player, you want to run in front of them, so that the sentry's knockback carries you rather than them.  There's probably special cases I'm not accounting for though (ie, wrangler) :)

Comment: So even if a player is capping a point, it'll target those that are closest to it?

Comment: The sentry cares not for your silly *points.*  It simply shoots at whatever is closest until it is destroyed or runs out of ammo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whoever is closest to the Sentry Gun within its range will be targeted by it. If the target moves away such that another target becomes the closest, the Sentry Gun will switch to that next closest target. This is why during an ÜberCharge, it's recommended that a Medic stand between his patient and the sentry to tank its gunfire, so that his patient can damage it.

Highly-coordinated team movements could *theoretically* cause a sentry to turn back and forth without allowing it to open much fire and cause too much damage, but given a typical game's fast pace, I haven't observed that happen yet.

Note that it doesn't matter what a target is *doing*; only their position relative to the Sentry Gun matters. Whether the Scout is on the control point or not, if he's the closest to the Sentry Gun then it will fire at him. Whether the Demoman or Heavy is firing at it, whoever is closest will be targeted.

Also, if there's a Spy using [Your Eternal Reward](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Your_Eternal_Reward), then as long as he is disguised he will never be targeted by a Sentry Gun, even if he backstabs somebody while already disguised and within its range.

Comment: Maybe it's good to mention the fact that even if the closest person is a bonked scout or ubered medic/target the gun will still shoot them, hence the effectiveness of bonked scouts

Comment: Just to add to the point about the Your Eternal Reward: I'm pretty sure that the YER does not protect you if the Sentry is *already* targeting you. If you don't have a disguise while you're targeted by the sentry, and stab someone (gaining a disguise) the sentry will continue to target and shoot at you until you a) drop out of sight/range, b) aren't the closest target, or c) cloak

Comment: @Robotnik: That is correct.